# React Modals visible for a split-second on page load

Tags: css, reactjs, modal-dialog

I am rendering modals in React.

My `index.html` looks like this:

```
<div id="root"></div>
<div id="modal"></div>
```

And all my modals are rendered (through a portal) as a child of `.modal`.

Each modal element has the following form:

```
<div class="modal-background open">
    <!-- children -->
</div>
```

Where the class can be `modal-background open` or `modal-background closed`. The entire component is:

```
interface OwnProps {
    children: React.ReactNode
    isOpen: boolean
    onExit: () => void
}

export class Modal extends React.Component<OwnProps, any> {

    _exit = () => this.props.onExit();

    _renderModal = () => (
        <div className={`modal-background ${this.props.isOpen ? "open" : "closed"}`} onClick={this._exit}>
            {this.props.children}
        </div>
    );

    render() {
        if (this.props.isOpen) {
            document.body.className += " no-scroll";
        } else {
            document.body.classList.remove("no-scroll");
        }
        let elem = document.querySelector("#modal");
        if (elem == null) {
            console.log("Could not render modal.");
            return null;
        }
        return ReactDOM.createPortal(this._renderModal(), elem);
    }
}
```

And the CSS looks like:

```
.modal-background {
    /* Other styling - this a dark backdrop for a modal child */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    transition: opacity 150ms ease-out;

    &.closed {
        opacity: 0; 
        pointer-events: none;
    }

    &.open {
        pointer-events: all;
        opacity: 1; 

        &:hover {
            cursor: pointer;    
        }
    }
}
```

So my modal is used like `<Modal><CustomModalElement/></Modal>`.

When I load the page, my modal elements briefly flash, indicating that they are not hidden on load (but a split-second afterwards).

I can fix this by adding `display: none` and `display: inherit` into the css, but then I miss the nice transitions.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you need to do anything else inside your `index.html` file except

```
<body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <div id="modal"></div>
```

And for your `Modal.js`, you could try something along these lines:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const Modal = props => {
  return ReactDOM.createPortal(
    <div className="ui dimmer modals visible active">
      <div className="ui standard modal visible active">
        <div className="header">Delete Object</div>
        <div className="content">
          Are you sure you want to delete this?
        </div>
        <div className="actions">
          <button className="ui primary button">Delete</button>
          <button className="ui button">Cancel</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>,
    document.querySelector("#modal")
  );
};

export default Modal;
```

and then inside your other component where the user will execute the modal:

```
import React from "react";
import Modal from "../Modal"; // or wherever your Modal is in the file tree

const ObjectDelete = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      ObjectDelete
      <Modal />
    </div>
  );
};

export default ObjectDelete;
```

Keep in mind that the example of modal I offer here is not a reusable component.